# boost interprocess scoped lock with timer blocks despite should return

Tags: c++, boost-thread, boost-interprocess

I have some code of my application that makes usage of `boost inteprocess scoped lock with timers`. When a mutex is acquired in one thread, a second thread tyring to acquire it for few milliseconds will fail and will log something to screeen.

I don't know why but with the version of boost 1.50 this doens't work anymore.
The code below I can see that the thread #2 doesn't print "ERROR" but is completely stuck.

Am I missing something here?

I am using LINUX kernel 2.6.32 with g++.

COuld it be something to deal with UTC? I read o boost that the time used by such lock is UTC and in date time I am reading right now about `local_adjustor` and conversion from local to utc and vice-versa.

AFG

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
   #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
   #include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
   #include <boost/thread.hpp>
   #include <boost/bind.hpp>

   namespace bi = boost::interprocess;


   void  lock_test( bi::named_mutex& mt, bool long_sleep ) { 

           boost::posix_time::ptime pt = 
             boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()
             +  boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100);

            bi::scoped_lock<bi::named_mutex> l( mt, pt );
            if( l.owns() ){
            std::cout << "Locked"<<std::endl;
            }
            else{
            std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
            std::cout.flush();
            return ;
            }

            if(long_sleep){
                while(true) {sleep(1);std::cout<<"[]";std::cout.flush();}
            }
        }

        int main(){

               bi::named_mutex  m_mutex( bi::open_or_create, "ciao"
               , bi::permissions( 0666  ));
               boost::thread t1 = boost::thread( &lock_test
               , boost::ref( m_mutex), true );
               sleep(4);
               boost::thread t2 = boost::thread(  &lock_test
               , boost::ref(m_mutex), false );
               while(true){sleep(1);}
        }
```

Comment: You have't said what platform you're using, but on *NIX you can use strace, dtrace, truss or similar to find out what arguments are being passed to the system synchronization primitives, and where your threads are blocked

Comment: I updated my post. I am using LINUX. With strace I can see that a nanosleep continuosly called.

Comment: Looks like the scoped_lock should either use [sem_timedwait](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_timedwait), or `sem_trywait` with a yield loop if the `BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_TIMEOUTS` macro is not defined. Can you tell which is used, and whether that macro is defined?

Comment: HI. I ddebugged and the code is using sem_timedwait with BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_TIMEOUTS defined.

Comment: It looks that if I switch from boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()
 to boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time() everything works fine.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question - it might still help someone else!

Comment: I can do that but I would like someone that might confirm that this is the right solution for real. Is anybody able to confirm that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that if I switch from `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()` to

```
 boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()
```

everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `boost::get_system_time()`, there are quite a few examples with it. Though I can't find the authoritative source, I use `microsec_clock` exactly as you do and get similar problems. Just discovered the bug though, will update when I'll test the fix.

[Usage of boost::unique_lock::timed_lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200305/usage-of-boostunique-locktimed-lock)