# How to correctly use boost::timed_mutex and scoped_lock

Tags: c++, boost, locking, boost-thread, boost-mutex

I am trying to use both timed_mutex with the scoped_lock. I have successfully used the scoped_lock before by following some examples but now I don't seem to find my way around neither I am able to properly understand the boost documentation.

The desired behavior is the following: try to acquire an scoped_lock for x time, if successful return true otherwise return false.

Currently I have:

```
boost::timed_mutex _mutex;
boost::timed_mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(_mutex, boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::miliseconds(10));
```

However when I try to find (through boost documentation or examples) if this scoped_lock will return a boolean or not I find nothing or find really different ways to do it.

Therefore I ask which is the correct way to do it, how does it exactly works and maybe some indication as to how correctly "read" the documentation of boost.

UPDATE:

So

```
boost::timed_mutex _mutex;
boost::timed_mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(_mutex, boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::miliseconds(10));

if(scoped_lock.owns_lock()) {
    // exclusive code 
}
```

Will create a mutex which when I try to lock with scoped_lock.owns_lock() will try to acquire the lock during 10 miliseconds (in this case) and return false if the time's up and the lock wasn't acquired?

Comment: This question might help you: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200305/usage-of-boostunique-locktimed-lock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.timed_mutex), `boost::timed_mutex::scoped_lock` is just an alias for `boost::unique_lock<timed_mutex>`:

```
class timed_mutex:
    boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    // ...

    typedef unique_lock<timed_mutex> scoped_timed_lock;
    typedef unspecified-type scoped_try_lock;
    typedef scoped_timed_lock scoped_lock;

    // ...
};
```

Now checking out the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.unique_lock) for `boost::unique_lock`, it shows that there are two ways to determine if you own the lock:

```
template<typename Lockable>
class unique_lock
{
public:
    // ...

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept;
    bool owns_lock() const noexcept;

    // ...
};
```

Therefore, you can do either

```
if(scoped_lock) {
    // we have the lock, yay!
}
```

or

```
if(scoped_lock.owns_lock()) {
    // we have the lock, yay!
}
```

Incidentally, unique_lock has a constructor that takes relative time as a chrono::duration, which may or may not be cleaner than using absolute time.

Edit:
Given this code:

```
boost::timed_mutex _mutex;
boost::timed_mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(_mutex,
           boost::get_system_time() + boost::posix_time::miliseconds(10)); // <-- attempt to acquire mutex happens here!

if(scoped_lock.owns_lock()) {
    // exclusive code 
}
```

The attempt to acquire the mutex happens at the time the lock is constructed, not at the time `owns_lock()` is called. Yes, the exclusive code will only execute if you successfully acquired the mutex. I'm not sure what you mean by "return false" - this code doesn't return anything. If `owns_lock()` returns false, then you have failed to acquire the mutex and can't run the exclusive code, and you can communicate this to your caller anyway you want.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect your information and make sure I've understood it well, please confirm I am right!